# QtDesigner & PySide: QTableWidget don't get accessible

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside, qtablewidget

I made a form in QtDesigner. This form gets loaded from PySide with help of the function

```
widget = loader.load(file, parent)
```

However, the QTableWidget (with objectNname buffer_table) don't get accessible with

```
widget.buffer_table
```

If I use a QPushButton instead it works. How can I get this working.
I'd like to fill up the table in Python.

This is the ui-file i'd like to use: http://pastebin.com/6PZFrvmr

EDIT:
When I create a new table and try to load it, it seems to work. However, if I put it in a QTabWidget I can't access it.

EDIT2:
`widget.findChild(QWidget, "buffer_table")`: Search & find is the trick!

Comment: Could you post your .ui file ?

Comment: @alexisdm: i've edited the post and added the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to see if the table is there with: `widget.findChild(QWidget, "buffer_table")` (even from the parent, since it is a recursive search).

Comment: ok, seems that the problem is deeper. thanks for your engagement. the pyside python code is executed in IDAPython (python module for IDA Pro). but if I try to acces widget.buffer_table this error appears: PySide.QtGui.QWidget has no attribute buffer_table.

Comment: I think the surrounding QTabWidget may be a problem.

Comment: @AkaBkn You could try to see if the table is there with: `widget.findChild(QWidget, "buffer_table")` (even from the parent, since it is a recursive search).

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. It works now except that it overwrites the header with (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...). Seems that if I put something in a QTabWidget, QToolBox or QStackedWidget it generates no pointer-attribute in widget. but finding is ok, too.

Comment: Phew, that was my fault. Did a clear() on the table which does delete the headers too.