# Using QUiLoader and UI files in PySide to dynamically create user interface at run-time

Tags: python, pyside, qt-designer

I'm really having a hard time connecting slots from `Python` to `Qt Designer` `UI` files.
I've been through all tutorials I could find on `PySide` (ex: http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/eventsandsignals/)

Its quite easy when you set up the *GUI* in code, but we really would like to use Qt Designer and UI files.

Some other threads just points to the use of `pyuic` to convert `.ui` to `.py` files, but if its possible I would really like to do this at run-time.

Here is my code so far. 
I have no clue how to connect the `connectBtn` to the `Connect` in the UI file :

```
def initUI(self):      

    loader = QUiLoader()
    file = QFile("designer_test.ui")
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    myWidget = loader.load(file, self)
    #print(dir(myWidget))
    file.close()

    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(myWidget)
    self.setLayout(layout)

    connectBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Connect", self)

    connectBtn.clicked.connect(self.connectClicked)

    myWidget.setWindowTitle('Window')
    myWidget.show()

def connectClicked(self):
    print("works")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked this page: [Using a Designer UI File in Your Application](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html)

It is for C++, but I think the concepts are the same as what you're trying to do in python.

According to that page, to get the widgets that are created by the Ui file you need to call findChild().

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250727/qtdesigner-pyside-qtablewidget-dont-get-accessible).

Answer (score 0):

I've made this [auto-connector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartside) to help me with this... please take a look at it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.