# How to read widgets in .ui file with PySide

Tags: qt4, pyside

I'm trying to access `Qt` elements that are loaded via .ui file. However I'm getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'TreeviewWidgetSelectProve' object has no attribute '_treeview'
```

Full [python code](http://pastebin.com/S2N86bJC) and [.ui file](http://pastebin.com/42MHLcZe) are available in those links respectively. Code snippet:

```
    ui_file_path = os.path.join(
        '/home/userdaze/pyside_test', 'resource', 'treeview.ui')

    loader = QUiLoader(self)
    ui_file = QFile(ui_file_path)
    self._widget_top = loader.load(ui_file, self)

    self._treeview = self._widget_top.findChild(QTreeView, '_treeview')
    self._treeview.setModel(self._std_model)
```

Whether I use `findChild` suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250727/qtdesigner-pyside-qtablewidget-dont-get-accessible) doesn't change the situation. It returns `NoneType` if in use.

What is wrong? Thank you!

python-pyside 1.1.1-3 on Ubuntu Quantal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid your .ui file is broken.
Have you tried opening it in the QtDesigner? When I do that it reports an error.
So I recreated the file with QtDesigner (just a QMainWindows with a QTreeView) and your problem disappears.

There are plenty of other problems though:

- self has no member uiw (line 33 and 38)
- passing the instance of TreeviewWidgetSelectProve to the QUiLoader does not work as far as I know, thats why I had to implement a custom loader: https://github.com/ros-visualization/python_qt_binding/blob/groovy-devel/src/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py#L199

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the codes somehow while removing unnecessary parts. Now they're updated.